# OSX 10.7.5 - Ruby on Rails LoadError: Could not open library 'sodium': dlopen(sodium, 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, dlopen

After typing rake db:create i get:

```
LoadError: Could not open library 'sodium': dlopen(sodium, 5): image not found.
Could not open library 'libsodium.dylib': dlopen(libsodium.dylib, 5): image not found
```

Here's some more output.

```
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium.rb:12:in `extended'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium/version.rb:8:in `extend'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium/version.rb:8:in `<module:Version>'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium/version.rb:5:in `<module:Sodium>'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium/version.rb:4:in `<module:RbNaCl>'
/Users/Mao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rbnacl-3.1.1/lib/rbnacl/sodium/version.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You probably don't have [sodium](http://labs.opendns.com/2013/03/06/announcing-sodium-a-new-cryptographic-library/) cryptographic library installed. If you are using MacPorts, install it with:

```
sudo port install libsodium
```

or with the Homebrew:

```
brew install libsodium
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker, you need to add it to your Dockerfile and do a re-build.